# Limit the importxml to a defined span

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

Currently I am using a transpose and then another column to count the results and give me what I want. But because Tanaike is awesome and helped me on another section, I am trying to wrap my head around what he did and apply it to this.

Starting with this URL in A1,

```
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/307-N-Rosedale-Ave-Tulsa-OK-74127/22151896_zpid/
```

This is the formula in A2:

```
=If($A$1:A="","",Transpose(importxml($A1:$A,"//span[@class='snl phone']")))
```

Based on the listing sometimes there are three phone numbers, sometimes four, and sometimes eight that get spread across as many columns as needed.

I am looking for the Property Owner phone number. This is the ELEMENT from the inspection.

```
<div class="info flat-star-ratings sig-col" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1506365934526_2361">  <span class="snl name notranslate">Property Owner</span>           <span class="snl phone" id="yui_3_18_1_2_1506365934526_2360">(918) 740-1698 </span>    </div>
```

So I tried this, and it comes up content is empty. I was thinking to look at the div class info flat, then within that the snl phone, and stop before the /end of span.

```
=importXML(B17,"//div[@class='info flat-star-ratings sig-col']//span[@class='snl phone']/@span")
```

What I really need is ONLY the property owner phone number with 95% or greater accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification of XPath query?

### Modified XPath query :

```
=importxml(A1,"//div[@class='info flat-star-ratings sig-col']//span[@class='snl phone']")
```

### Result :

[image]

If this is not data you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

4th and 8th number are the same. Is my understanding correct? If it's no problem. Please put URL and a following formula to "A1" and "A2", respectively.

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='info flat-star-ratings sig-col']//span[@class='snl name notranslate']")="Property Owner",IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='info flat-star-ratings sig-col']//span[@class='snl phone']"), "")),"Select * where Col1<>''")
```

#### Result :

[image]

Comment: That is the data. Is there a way to limit it to 'Property Owner' in this case it is the 4th and 8th number....

Got it. I took what you did, wrapped it in an index with a counta/2 because it always produces 4 6 or 8 results, and Property Owner is always the 2nd 3rd or 4th result.







=Index(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='info flat-star-ratings sig-col']//span[@class='snl phone']"),Counta(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='info flat-star-ratings sig-col']//span[@class='snl phone']")),1)


I do not know how to wrap code in the comment section. tell me and ill fix it.

Comment: @Arlen Gregory I updated my answer. Please confirm it. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: That will work better than what I came up with dividing results by 2 and taking the last.